# Change Lead owner trigger before insert

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I have a trigger change owner before insert a new lead record.

```
trigger trickOnLead on Lead (before insert) { 
   for (Lead ld : Trigger.new) {
         if(ld.testId__c != null ){
             ld.ownerid = ld.testId__c; 
         }
   }
}
```

---

I tested it through web-to-lead, and its successful.(on Monday, July 8th),
but today its not work anymore ?!
note that it only work for manual create a new record.

Thanks,
Manh

Comment: Please provide some more info. What exactly doesn't work? Does the trigger gets fired? Is testId__c != null ?

Comment: Thanks Moti !, the trigger got fired, but it not update ownerid. I just add before update and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trigger trickOnLead on Lead (before insert, before update) { 
   for (Lead ld : Trigger.new) {
         if(ld.testId__c != null ){
             ld.ownerid = ld.testId__c; 
         }
   }
}
```